# issue in file write

Tags: django, file-io, python-2.7, django-views

I've been struggling with this for a few hours. I want to send a text file generated by Django to another server. For that I use scp and `subprocess.call()`. Everything goes well and I got a `return_code == 0`, but scp sends 0 bytes. The file created on the server side is empty.

I printed the exact command executed, the path is right, and if I put in in a shell it works perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
form = SubmitForm(request.POST or None)
context['form'] = form
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        # write file in ~/hipercic/apps/dcor/jobs/
        params_file = open('apps/dcor/jobs/job_' + datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") + '_params.txt', 'wb')
        for key, val in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
            params_file.write(str(val) + ' \n')
        params_file.close       
        cmd = 'scp /home/guillet/hipercic/' + params_file.name + ' guillet@helios.public.stolaf.edu:'
        context['cmd'] = cmd
        return_code = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
        context['return_code'] = return_code
        return render(request, 'base_pending.html', context)
```

I thought about a possible race condition, the file not having time to be completely written before being send, but nothing changes with a time.sleep(3).

Also, something really weird and the heart of the issue, if I tried to reopen and read the file right after closing it, the file is empty:

```
with open('/home/guillet/hipercic/' + params_file.name, 'rb') as f:
    print f.read() # prints nothing!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have done `params_file.close` instead of `params_file.close()`

Closing the file properly will flush the data to the file you want to write to

It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes.

Comment: Duh.Thanks. I'm really ashamed.